# cannot resolve '@GET'

Tags: java, android, api

@GET is showing error I don't know why
So my **code** was in java :

```
package com.example.goodNews;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.GET;


public interface RetrofitAPI {
    @GET
    Call<NewsModal> getAllNews(@Url String url);

}
```

Edited: Ooops my mistake, their was a typo in my gradleBuild.Dependnecies file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check gradle-> app -> dependencies -> com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0 is exist

Comment: Thanks, it was my bad instead of "squreup"  I wrote "squarepu".